# PHP Sending Email but body just got Array message

Tags: php, email

I'm just starting to learn PHP and I'm trying to send my table via email. I am receiving the email but the body just says `Array`. I dont know where to go from here, please help.

This is how my table is being displayed, and the send mail function in there as well

```
    <form action="assign.php" method="post"><?php

if(is_array($result)){
    echo '
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Assign Ticket</legend>
        <div>Changes will affect updated rows only.</div>
        <p></p>
        <table width=auto cellpadding=1px cellspacing=0px border=1 align=center id=assign>

            <thead>
            <tr>';      

    // column comment from DB as column header
    foreach($result[0] as $key => $val){
        echo '<th align=center>'.$colcomments[$key].'</th>';
        }
    echo '
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
    foreach($result as $row => $info){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($info as $key => $val){
    if($key=='id'){
    echo '<td title="'.$colcomments[$key].'">'.$val.'.<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']" value="'.$val.'" id="rowid_'.$val.'" /></td>';
         }
    else {
    echo '<td title="'.$colcomments[$key].'"><input type="text" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']" value="'.$val.'" /></td>';
         }
         }
    echo '</tr>'; 
         }
    echo '
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </fieldset>';

    if($result) {
        $Body = "<html>\n"
            . "<head>\n"
            . "</head>\n"
            . "<body>\n"
            . $result
            . "</body>\n"
            . "</html>\n";
    //Setting up Mail
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
            // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            //useful for debugging, shows full SMTP errors
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
            // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
            // Enable encryption, usually SSL/TLS
            if (defined(EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION)) {
                $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
            }
            // Specify host server
            $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
            $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
            $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        } else {
            $mail->IsMail();
        }
        $mail->From = EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS;
        $mail->FromName = EMAIL_FROM_NAME;
        $mail->AddAddress('sample.test@domain.COM');
        $mail->Subject = 'Ticket Assignment - ';
        $mail->WordWrap = 100;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $Body;
        $mail->Send();
    }
}

?>

  <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Date</legend>
        <div>Select Date from and Date to</div>
        <p></p>
        <input type="date" name="from" id="from" value="<?=$date['from']; ?>" />
        <input type="date" name="to" id="to" value="<?=$date['to']; ?>" />
        <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Here is the smtp debug result that I am getting,

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\*\assign.php on line 260
```

Which refers to this,

```
. "</body>\n"
```

Comment: You're including your database array `$result` in your `$Body` string

Comment: It actually refers to the line before that, `$result` is an array, so you can't just do a `echo $result`.

Comment: any idea what I should put in the `$Body`? i was thinking that since `$result` was used to hold the arrays it can be exploded in the email as well to a resulting tables. Sorry newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by using a function.

```
function two_dim_array_to_html_table($arr, $colcomments){
    $ret = "<table border='1' width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' align='center'>\n";
    $ret .= "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach($arr[0] as $key => $val){
        $ret .= "\t\t<th>".$colcomments[$key]."</th>\n";
        }
    $ret .= "\t</tr>\n";
    foreach($arr as $row){
        $ret .= "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach($row as $column){
            $ret .= "\t\t<td>".$column."</td>\n";
            }
        $ret .= "\t</tr>\n";
        }
    $ret .= "<table>\n";
    return $ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test but i guess this code will fix your issue try it

```
if($result) {
            $Body = "<html>\n"
                . "<head>\n"
                . "</head>\n"
                . "<body>\n"
             .json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).


                . "</body>\n"
                . "</html>\n";
```

Comment: It didn't work, I'm getting the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\*\assign.php on line 259`

Comment: Try to correct the syntax error its easy , i can't test it

Comment: Line 259 refers to `. <?php`

Comment: Still error - `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\*\assign.php on line 259` and it refers to `. foreach ($result as $l){`

Comment: true add => $val this should be work i edited again my answer

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your effort but it's the same error as the last one.

Comment: This is the best i can provide try this and if you dont like the format look how to change it . have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your line immediately above 260.
    $result
is an array, so you can't just concatenate it with other strings.

You can't use;

```
'<body>'.$result.'</body>'
```

You can use;

```
'<body>'.json_encode($result).'</body>'
```

(Or any other function that converts your array to a string)

I hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it seemed to half work because I'm seeing other messages now in the body but it does not seem to have the same format as how i sees it in my browser, and all I get is this

`[{"id":"21","testid1":"test7","testid2":"test7","summary":"test7","type":"test7","tested_by":"TEST","start_date":"2017-01-03","Tester":""}]`